# Using CMake with Eclipse CDT, quickly switch targets?

Tags: eclipse, cmake, eclipse-cdt

I'm using the CDT4 - MinGW Makefiles generator. Project->Build All successfully builds the target (a shared library) but it seems I would have to (A) open a project settings page and type in the target, hoping it's spelled right*, or (B) run make from a terminal to "build" the install and package targets.

I noticed a promising Project->Make Target entry, but the Create... and Build... sub-entries are greyed-out.

Any hints would be appreciated!

*http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/rsdhelp/v7r0m0/topic/org.eclipse.cdt.doc.user/concepts/cdt_c_build_over.htm

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For anyone else wondering, `Project->Make Target->Build...` presents you with the list of targets available. It will only be available (Using Galileo) **if the Project Explorer has focus**.

Then, it will only show targets for whatever directory is selected (so make sure your project is selected, unless you only want to build 'src' for example. Alternatively, just right-click the project in the Project Explorer.

A bit more cumbersome than the way Code::Blocks handles Makefiles, but it is Eclipse, after all.